# Put multiple data sorted into one variable (like HashMap just with more rows)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to receive data from my MySQL database and save all of the rows with multiple variables in them and put them into one variable.

My database:

```
############################################
#192.168.1.1 | Instance1 | 19.988 | 0 | 20 #
############################################

############################################
#192.168.1.2 | Instance2 | 19.878 | 1 | 19 #
############################################

and so on...
```

From this database I receive the data which is contained in the entries/rows (unique key is the IP address [first entry])

Now my goal is it to store all of this data in one variable so I can list all of my instances and show the according data to them.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to store this data in one variable (something like a HashMap just with more rows) or is there maybe even a better way to store the data?

Comment: Are you asking how to store the contents of a DB table into a `Map`? How does your current data access code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single HashMap object to store the multiple records that come from your SQL query.

After setting up your database connection and performing your query, just go through the ResultSet object, create an object using a model class and add it to the HashMap using the IP as the key. The code below shows an example of how to do it:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database", "db_user", "db_password");

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table");
            HashMap<String, DBRecord> results = new HashMap<>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                results.put(resultSet.getString(1), new DBRecord(
                        resultSet.getString(1),
                        resultSet.getString(2),
                        resultSet.getFloat(3),
                        resultSet.getInt(4),
                        resultSet.getInt(5)
                ));
            }
            connection.close();
            printHashMap(results);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void printHashMap(HashMap<String, DBRecord> records) {
        for (Map.Entry pair : records.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static class DBRecord {

        private String ip, instance;
        private double firstValue;
        private int secondValue, thirdValue;

        public DBRecord(String ip, String instance, double firstValue, int secondValue, int thirdValue) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.instance = instance;
            this.firstValue = firstValue;
            this.secondValue = secondValue;
            this.thirdValue = thirdValue;
        }

        //Gets and sets...

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ip + " | " + instance + " | " + firstValue + " | " + secondValue + " | " + thirdValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Using the HashMap you can retrieve the results from the object using the key (IP), but you could also use an ArraList or some other data structure to store your records, although you would need to change how you go through them.

I hope this helps you.